# Apache ProxyPass server_name extension

Tags: apache, rhel7

I have an Apache server that uses ProxyPass to communicate with some public endpoints, and it performs mutual authentication and so on. However, I'm facing an issue with one of these services that it reaches because it performs a check on the server_name indicated in the client hello. It seems that Apache is not properly evaluating it. Below is an example of a test I conducted using wget and one through the Apache proxy:

wget:

```
New TCP connection #2: xxxxxx(53864) \<-\> xxxx.it(443)
2 1  0.0223 (0.0223)  C\>S  Handshake
ClientHello
Version 3.3
cipher suites
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
\[…\]
TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
compression methods
NULL
extensions
server_name
host_name: xxxxxx.it
```

Proxy apache:

```
New TCP connection #3: xxxxxx(54730) \<-\> xxxxxx.it(443)
3 1  0.0215 (0.0215)  C\>S  Handshake
ClientHello
Version 3.3
resume \[32\]=
f4 35 6c 3d e6 ea 0a 84 85 56 43 a1 6c e1 58 d5
90 40 b2 78 73 8b 96 21 90 11 33 d2 0e a6 77 d0
cipher suites
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
\[…\]
compression methods
NULL
extensions
encrypt_then_mac
extended_master_secret
signature_algorithms
3 2  0.0227 (0.0012)  S\>C  Handshake
ServerHello
Version 3.3
session_id\[32\]=
f4 35 6c 3d e6 ea 0a 84 85 56 43 a1 6c e1 58 d5
90 40 b2 78 73 8b 96 21 90 11 33 d2 0e a6 77 d0
cipherSuite         TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
compressionMethod                   NULL
extensions
```

Any advice? The wget was performed from the same Apache server, and there are no firewalls in between that could be causing the issue.

Thanks.

I would like the calls that pass through Apache's ProxyPass to include the server_name extension in the client hello.

Comment: Look at `ProxyPreserveHost On`